# How to parse content from a link that redirects to another link in R?

Tags: r, redirect

I am trying to parse the news content from Reuters based on links extracted from their RSS.

However, the links I gotten from RSS will redirect me to another page where the content is actually stored.

May I know how can i parse the news content based on the link extracted from RSS?

I have tried the following:

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(httr)

xml.url <- "http://feeds.reuters.com/news/economy"
script  <- getURL(xml.url)
doc     <- xmlParse(script)
links   <- xpathSApply(doc,'//item/link',xmlValue)
script  <- getURL(links[1])
```

The 'script' obtained only contains the redirect link. Hence, I tried to extract the redirect link in order to go  to the news page.

```
redirect    <- xmlParse(script)
redirect.link <- xpathSApply(redirect,"//A/@HREF")
script1  <- getURL(redirect.link)
```

But getURL from the redirected link will return me an empty string.

Comment: Sorry. Resolved. I am using the wrong link from xml.url... although I am still curious if there is anyway to handle url that redirects to another url